# Simple graph representation in Scheme

Tags: variables, graph, scheme

I am trying to implement very simple graph in Scheme like this:

```
'( (node1 '(node2 node3) ) (node2 '() )  (node3 '()) )
```

List of lists, but now I need to store the graph list in a variable.
I tried using define

```
(define graph '())
```

And then using this procedure for adding more nodes to the list.

```
(define (add-node name children) (list graph (list name children)))
```

It works as expected:

```
(add-node 1 '(2 3))
```

returns : '(() (1 (2 3)))

The problem is I failed to update the graph with the newly added node.
Trying to redefine the graph causes "Already defined error", tying to use let/let! caused "Cannot modify constant error"

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Thanks to @Óscar López

I came up with a solution for my problem.
I am not a scheme guru but here is my code ( atleast it works :) )

```
;Define the empty graph 
(define graph '())

; Graph mutator. All modify operations use this procedure 
(define (modify-graph newGraph)
 (set! graph newGraph)
  graph)

; Adds a node to the graph ( name '(chidren) )  (add-node 1 '(2 3))
(define (add-node name children)
  (define (add-node-helper name children graph)
  (cons (list name children) graph))
  (modify-graph (add-node-helper name children graph)))

; Generic procedure which removes elements from list that match certain condition
(define (remove-element elements condition?)
  (cond ((empty? elements) elements)
        ((condition? (car elements)) (remove-element (cdr elements) condition?))
        (else (cons (car elements) (remove-element (cdr elements) condition? ))))
  )


; Removes a node, and all references to it.
(define (remove name)
  (define (remove-node name)
  (define (condition? element)
    (eq? (car element) name))
  (remove-element graph condition?))

  (define (remove-all-refs name)
    (define (remove-child name node)
      (define (condition? element)
        (eq? name element))
      (cons (car node) (list (remove-element (cadr node) condition?))))

    (define (remove-all-refs-helper name graph)
      (cond ((empty? graph) graph)
            (else (cons (remove-child name (car graph))  (remove-all-refs-helper name (cdr graph))))))

  (remove-all-refs-helper name graph))

  (modify-graph (remove-node name))
  (modify-graph (remove-all-refs name))  
 )
```

The end result is:

```
(add-node 1 '(2 3))
(add-node 3 '(5 6))
(add-node 2 '(7 8 9 10 11))
> graph ;-> '((2 (7 8 9 10 11)) (3 (5 6)) (1 (2 3)))
```

also the remove node removes all references to a given node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid mutating globally defined data, and your `add-node` procedure doesn't seem right (the graph will be nested inside a list every time it's called). I suggest this:

```
(define (add-node name children graph)
  (cons (list name children) graph))
```

That is: pass the graph as a parameter, and return a list with the newly added node. Then recursively pass around the modified graph (preferred) or modify a variable with its value (discouraged):

```
; good idea
(procedure-that-modifies-graph (add-node name children graph))

; not recommended
(let ((graph '()))
  (set! graph (procedure-that-modifies graph (add-node name children))))
```

In Scheme, the recommended style is to avoid mutating variables, if something needs to be changed you create a new object that includes the modification (a list of nodes in this case) and pass it to a procedure that receives it as a parameter, we do this as many times as needed, possibly in a recursive fashion.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delayed response. I went with your "Not recommended", because I felt it was more comfortable for the end user. I have updated my answer with the code I came up with. Thanks again :)